# Updating a UserProfile and its Roles using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to find a way that would allow me to update a UserProfile entity along with a list of Roles that the user is assigned to.  I've written the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
public void UpdateUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
{
  context.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Added;

  var databaseRoleIds = context.Roles
    .Where(r => r.UserProfiles
      .Any(u => u.UserId == userProfile.UserId))
      .Select(r => r.RoleId).ToList();

  var clientRoleIds = userProfile.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).ToList();

  var removedRoleIds = databaseRoleIds.Except(clientRoleIds).ToList();

  var addedRoleIds = clientRoleIds.Except(databaseRoleIds).ToList();

  var unchangedRoleIds = removedRoleIds.Union(addedRoleIds).ToList();

  foreach (var roleId in unchangedRoleIds)
  {
    var role = context.Roles.Find(roleId);
    context.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
  }

  foreach (var roleId in removedRoleIds)
  {
    userProfile.RemoveRole(context.Roles.Find(roleId));
  }

  foreach (var roleId in addedRoleIds)
  {
    userProfile.AddRole(context.Roles.Find(roleId));
  }

  context.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;

}
```

Here is the unitOfWork

```
namespace MvcWebsite.WorkUnits
{
public class WorkUnit : IWorkUnit, IDisposable
{
private MvcContext context = new MvcContext();
private RoleRepository roleRepository;
private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

public IRoleRepository RoleRepository
{
  get
  {
    if (this.roleRepository == null)
    {
      roleRepository = new RoleRepository(context);
    }
    return roleRepository;
  }
}

public IUserProfileRepository UserProfileRepository
{
  get
  {
    if (this.userProfileRepository == null)
    {
      userProfileRepository = new UserProfileRepository(context);
    }
    return userProfileRepository;
  }
}

public void Save()
{
  context.SaveChanges();
}

private bool disposed = false;

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (!this.disposed)
  {
    if (disposing)
    {
      context.Dispose();
    }
  }
  this.disposed = true;
}

public void Dispose()
{
  Dispose(true);
  GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

}
}
```

... and here is the HttpPost Edit method

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfileEditViewModel model)
    {
      try
      {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          var clientUserProfile = new UserProfile();
          clientUserProfile.UserId = model.UserId;
          clientUserProfile.UserName = model.UserName;
          clientUserProfile.FirstName = model.FirstName;
          clientUserProfile.LastName = model.LastName;
          clientUserProfile.Email = model.Email;
          clientUserProfile.RowVersion = model.RowVersion;
          clientUserProfile.Roles = new List<Role>();
          foreach(var role in model.Roles)
          {
            if (role.Assigned)
            {
              clientUserProfile.Roles.Add(new Role
              {
                RoleId = role.RoleId,
                RoleName = role.RoleName,
                RowVersion = role.RowVersion,
              });
            }

          }
          unitOfWork.UserProfileRepository.UpdateUserProfile(clientUserProfile);
          unitOfWork.Save();
          return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = clientUserProfile.UserId });

        }
      }
      catch (DataException ex)
      {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes.  Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
      }
      return View(model);
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?  Or could suggest a tutorial somewhere that actually works.  Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're changing the entity state around, but you're not calling `SaveChanges()`. Do you do that outside of the function?

Comment: Yes, I've employed the UnitOfWork pattern, so this is method comes from UnitOfWork.UserProfileRepository.UpdateUserProfile.  This UnitOfWork holds a single context that is passed to each repository used and then calls SaveChanges on that context.  I've edited the code above to show the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new `UserProfile` in your controller, get the `UserProfile` from the repository, modify its fields, then send it back to `UpdateUserProfile` and call `Save`.

Comment: That was what I thought of at first, but that will change the OriginalValue of RowVersion, if another user has updated in the meantime.  Entity Framework uses the (read only) OriginalValues when it compares entities to assess if a concurrency violation has occured

Comment: It seems you are facing two distinct issues: 1) Updating an Entity and 2) Concurrency Strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that I had it totally wrong in the first place.  I wasn't changing the relationships at all.  I've included the code below, which allows me to attach the parent entity as modified and then mark the relationships as added and deleted as required

```
public void UpdateUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
{
  context.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
  var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

  foreach (var role in userProfile.Roles)
  {
    context.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
  }

  var databaseRoleIds = context.Roles
    .Where(r => r.UserProfiles
      .Any(u => u.UserId == userProfile.UserId))
      .Select(r => r.RoleId)
      .ToList();

  var clientRoleIds = userProfile.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).ToList();

  var removedRoleIds = databaseRoleIds.Except(clientRoleIds).ToList();

  var addedRoleIds = clientRoleIds.Except(databaseRoleIds).ToList();

  foreach (var roleId in removedRoleIds)
  {
    var role = context.Roles.Find(roleId);
    objectContext
      .ObjectStateManager
      .ChangeRelationshipState(userProfile, role, u => u.Roles, EntityState.Deleted);
  }

  foreach (var roleId in addedRoleIds)
  {
    var role = context.Roles.Find(roleId);
    objectContext
      .ObjectStateManager
      .ChangeRelationshipState(userProfile, role, u => u.Roles, EntityState.Added);
  }
}
```